# Origins of Young's Inequality

Tags: soft-question, young-inequality

I see Young's inequality (for products) pop up a lot in analysis, functional analysis, ODE, PDEs, etc...

I've seen a few proofs of it too. I'm just wondering, in what context did Young originally derive this?

I'm just trying to understand if its just some "random" observation that happened to be useful, or if originated somewhere then found lots of other applications.